# JSF/Primefaces doesn't validate @AssertTrue

Tags: validation, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish

my entity class look like this:

```
public class TimeFrame implements Serializable {    
@NotNull
private Date startTime;
@NotNull
@Future
private Date stopTime;
```

To have the right order I added:

```
@AssertTrue(message="Wrong order")
public boolean isTimeFrameValid(){
    return this.startTime.before(stopTime);
}
```

Now, JSF/Primefaces should validate this directly after input.

```
<p:calendar id="aucstop" required="true" pages="2" value="#{transportbean.stopTime}"   >
                            <p:ajax event="dateSelect"  />  
                            <f:validateBean/>
                        </p:calendar>
```

For example, when putting a past date into "StopTime" I got immediately a message. The "isTimeValid"-Mothod however is only validated when the whole object ist being created. Any ideas how to validate this directly after input?

GF 3.1.1 PrimeFaces 3.4

Comment: add `immediate=true` to your `<p:calendar/>`

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, but nothing changes

Comment: which implementation of the jsr-303 do you use? any logs?